# Is mysql substring sufficient for getting a preview of a long string from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

I'm currently using Javascript Datatables to populate my HTML table. Then i noticed its very slow when i query this particular table which has a column that contains a very large string (approx size 300-800kb or even higher).

My first is solution is to exclude that column in the sql statement and only display when the user clicks on that particular row. Performing a simple query for retrieving the long string upon clicking)

As possible, i want to show a preview of that long string so i thought of using substring in mysql to only display the first 100 characters of that long string.

My questions are, would be using substring in mysql efficient or it will almost use the same cpu processing and ram usage for retrieving the long string itself?
I'm worried about using function substring that it might be reading/processing the 'whole' string itself that it uses more memory.

My last possible solution I'm planning to implement is to create another column which is a copy of the long string but only saves the first 100 characters. So basically its a column dedicated for preview. It this a good idea or a bad one?

Comment: What is the purpose of this "long string"? Is it data or free-form text of some sort? Define "very slow". Are you using `SELECT * FROM gigantotable` even when you only need a few fields? A summary column isn't a bad idea if that's how you're presenting the data most of the time.

Comment: @tadman the long string is for a content of an article. Its the most important data of the table. Very slow in a sense it loads slower than the rest of all the queries i have. Im using select * from table where portal_id = something limit 10 for this particular scenario.

Comment: @symcbean why benchmark all the scenarios when i can ask an expert who is more experienced in this kind of scenario. Testing one particular scenario is time consuming in my case. I'm not a benchmarking expert either so i cant rely on my own tests given this scenarios. Hope you got my point.

Comment: You still need to define "slower" so we have an idea of the magnitude of the problem. 1ms vs. 0.1ms is not a problem. 10s vs. 1ms is.

Comment: @tadman approximately it needs more than 15 seconds to load data in that particular table (in browser) vs my other tables. When i exclude the long string column from the query, i got almost instant response of 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: How long does it take database-wise? Maybe it's a layout problem in your browser if there's a lot of text.

Comment: @tadman its the same layout though. But database wise, using phpmyadmin time of execution i found out it's 0.0004 vs 0.1388 (table w/ long string)

Comment: DB time doesn't seem like a big deal. This is probably to do with client-side rendering, as the browser can really have to crunch to figure out how to arrange huge blocks of text.

Comment: @tadman I see. But if DB time is an issue what would be your approach to this kind of problem? Let's say because of the size of string of that particular column.

Comment: Check more closely with your browser diagnostic tools. Chrome has a very detailed breakdown of the time spent processing a request, including DNS resolution, waiting, transfer, and rendering. It's unlikely that the database is a huge problem here with *kilobytes* of data. It's only when you get up into tens to hundreds of megabytes you start to feel the drag. As always, benchmark to get more accurate results. Use `curl` to download without the browser to get a feel for the transfer times.

Comment: @Reuben: an expert would want to know what the storage is, the indexing, the IO contention, the load, the network bandwidth and latency, the application architecture, the database engine, the concurrency policy and lots of other things before hazarding a guess. You could test it in a fraction of the time needed to gather this data let alone publish it here.

Comment: @symcbean Again, I'm not an expert and i don't even know some of the terms you are using. I just want a rough idea of that particular scenario thats answers which would you prefer under the given circumstances. 
It's good that you mention those 'keywords' now i have more insight on what to search. Ill appreciate if you can recommend good source material about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article which states the use of substring is not processing the 'whole' string but only checks the start of each string and moves on.

Rather than creating a new column in the table for previews which consumes server size, the substring function is enough to create a preview of the long string with minimal processing.

[Substring vs position performance](http://snoyowie.com/2013/02/mysql-substring-vs-position-performance/)